# JSON data read into HTML not showing up

Tags: html, json

I have a json file called books.json:

```
[
    {"GFGUserName":"User-1", "NoofProblems":"150", "Totalscore":"100", "Articles":"30"},
    {"GFGUserName":"User-1", "NoofProblems":"150", "Totalscore":"100", "Articles":"30"},
    {"GFGUserName":"User-1", "NoofProblems":"150", "Totalscore":"100", "Articles":"30"},
    {"GFGUserName":"User-1", "NoofProblems":"150", "Totalscore":"100", "Articles":"30"},
    {"GFGUserName":"User-1", "NoofProblems":"150", "Totalscore":"100", "Articles":"30"}
]
```

I am converting this into a table with the following code:

```html
<html lang="en"> 

<head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  <title>GFG User Details</title> 

  <!-- INCLUDING JQUERY-->
  <script src= 
"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"> 
  </script> 

  <!-- CSS FOR STYLING THE PAGE -->
  <style> 
    table { 
      margin: 0 auto; 
      font-size: large; 
      border: 1px solid black; 
    } 

    h1 { 
      text-align: center; 
      color: #006600; 
      font-size: xx-large; 
      font-family: 'Gill Sans', 
        'Gill Sans MT', ' Calibri', 
        'Trebuchet MS', 'sans-serif'; 
    } 

    td { 
      background-color: #E4F5D4; 
      border: 1px solid black; 
    } 

    th, 
    td { 
      font-weight: bold; 
      border: 1px solid black; 
      padding: 10px; 
      text-align: center; 
    } 

    td { 
      font-weight: lighter; 
    } 
  </style> 
</head> 

<body> 
  <section> 
    <h1>GeeksForGeeks</h1> 

    <!-- TABLE CONSTRUCTION-->
    <table id='table'> 
      <!-- HEADING FORMATION -->
      <tr> 
        <th>GFG UserHandle</th> 
        <th>Practice Problems</th> 
        <th>Coding Score</th> 
        <th>GFG Articles</th> 
      </tr> 

      <script> 
        $(document).ready(function () { 

          // FETCHING DATA FROM JSON FILE 
          $.getJSON("books.json", 
              function (data) { 
            var student = ''; 

            // ITERATING THROUGH OBJECTS 
            $.each(data, function (key, value) { 

              //CONSTRUCTION OF ROWS HAVING 
              // DATA FROM JSON OBJECT 
              student += '<tr>'; 
              student += '<td>' + 
                value.GFGUserName + '</td>'; 

              student += '<td>' + 
                value.NoOfProblems + '</td>'; 

              student += '<td>' + 
                  value.TotalScore + '</td>'; 

              student += '<td>' + 
                  value.Articles + '</td>'; 

              student += '</tr>'; 
            }); 

            //INSERTING ROWS INTO TABLE 
            $('#table').append(student); 
          }); 
        }); 
      </script> 
  </section> 
</body> 

</html>
```

I copied this code straight from this website: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fetch-data-from-json-file-and-display-in-html-table-using-jquery/

However, when I open the HTML file, I only see the headers for the table and none of the data shows up. My json file and HTML file are in the same directory so I don't know why this is happening. Please help!

Comment: Have you tried logging the "value"

Comment: @MohammadFahadRao How do I do that? Sorry, I am new to HTML.

Comment: Inside your loop try to log your second parameter "value"
console.log(value) to see whether you are getting content or not
TO check in browser use ctrl+shift+i (in google chrome) and select console tab to check 
and if there are other error s there, mention them too please

Comment: @MohammadFahadRao I added console.log(value) as the first line inside the loop and have the following errors:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/kaant/Desktop/Nasa%20internship%20screen/books.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
books.json:1 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

How can I fix these? Thank you!

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino

use this chrome extension it will unblock the CORS issue then check what you get in console